# Kibana(Elasticsearch) count with uniq value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I use kibana-4

I logged like this,

```
{user_id: 1, taget: A}
{user_id: 1, taget: B}
{user_id: 1, taget: B}
{user_id: 1, taget: B}
{user_id: 2, taget: A}
{user_id: 2, taget: C}
```

And I want to draw Pie Chart(target count) that result like this.

```
A: 2, B: 1, C: 1
```

It means count only one by each user.
How can I do? Can I user only Kibana's visualize options? or add some elasticsearch input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `metrics` field select `Unique Count` aggregation -> `user_id` field

In `buckets` field select `terms` aggregation -> `target` field