# Filtering and find unique value in Kibana(Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I use kibana.

I want to filter some value and find unique count.

ex)

```
{ user_id: 1, type: "customer", action: "xxx" }
{ user_id: 1, type: "customer", action: "xxx" }
{ user_id: 1, type: "seller", action: "xxx" }   # user change type!!!
{ user_id: 2, type: "customer", action: "xxx" }
{ user_id: 2, type: "customer", action: "xxx" }
{ user_id: 3, type: "customer", action: "xxx" }
```

How can I count just customers.
I want to get
`customer_count: 2`

for example, in SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM users where user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE type = "seller")
```

Is there any query for this situation?

Comment: Using kibana you can do same as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116114/kibanaelasticsearch-count-with-uniq-value/37118777#37118777

Comment: @alpert actually I want to reject user_id 1, who has seller type, even though it has customer type logs

Comment: term-> customer will do that ?

Comment: @alpert won't work as it'll be inclusive of `type:seller`

Comment: @JaehyunShin Are the samples you mentioned different documents or the same document? If they are all indexed to the `user_id`, @alpert suggestion would work as the latest update would reflect whether he was a `customer`/`seller`/etc

Comment: @alpert there is no term -> customer, term -> type exists.

Comment: @VarunNatraaj is there any query like, `SELECT * FROM users where user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE type = "seller")

Comment: @JaehyunShin then instead of term use filter -> type:customer

Comment: @alpert Can I use filter query?

Comment: @JaehyunShin You'll have only two types? `customer` or `seller`?

Comment: @VarunNatraaj yes only 2 values in type column